# printing string containing variables in python

Tags: python

I am a novice python learner, though I know printing text containing strings and variables but I want to ask a basic question regarding this. Here is my code:

```
x=5                                                                                        
print ("the value of x is ",x)                                      
print "the value of x is",x
```

The first print command prints `('the value of x is ', 5)` while the second one prints, `the value of x is 5`. But `print ('hello')` & `print 'hello'` prints `hello` (the same), why?

Comment: Think about this, if `(x + y) + 1` made a tuple out of `x + y`, that would ruin everything! That's why one-tuples are made like `('hello', )` with that trailing comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print is a statement in py2x not function. so printing `("the value of x is ",x)` actually prints a tuple:

```
>>> type(('hello'))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(('hello',))  # notice the trailing `,` 
<type 'tuple'>
```

In py2x just remove the `()` to get the correct output:

```
>>> print "the value of x is","foo" 
the value of x is foo
```

or you can also import py3x's print function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print ("the value of x is","foo")
the value of x is foo
```

Comment: thanks, i understood what you said.Will you please suggest me what to do either continue python 2 or skip over to 3?

Comment: @ankushsharma Continue with py2.7 as most of the (external)libraries are still on py2x, and the differences between py2x and py3x can be found here:http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Because `('hello')` is just `'hello'`, not a 1-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Python 2.x, `print` is a statement and the comma makes the expression a tuple, which prints with parentheses.  Assuming Python 3.x, `print` is a function so the first prints normally and the second is a syntax error.

Comment: Typo, thinking ahead..fixed.